# Clearsilver Template System - Problem with cs_render() and CSOUTFUNC

Tags: c, template-engine, clearsilver

Extract from my code:

```
NEOERR*
func(void *,char *);
...
char* buf;
buf = (char*) malloc(1024);
HDF* hdf;
CSPARSE* cs;
hdf_init(&hdf);
hdf_set_value(hdf, "name", "foo"); 
cs_init(&cs, hdf);
strcpy(buf, "This is <?cs var:name ?>");
cs_parse_string(cs, buf, 1024);
cs_render(cs, NULL , func);
...
NEOERR*
func(void *b, char* a)
{
    printf("%s", a);
}
```

Output is:

```
This is<space>
```

If I use

```
strcpy(buf, "<?cs var:name ?>");
```

then the output is

```
foo
```

How can I use templating commands in combination with static text? What is wrong with my CSOUTFUNC-function?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The problem was the missing `return (STATUS_OK)` in the function `func (void *, char *)`. Solved.

Comment: *templating* ? ??? c? maybe you got the wrong tag?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the missing

```
return (STATUS_OK);
```

in the function

```
NEOERR*
func(void *,char *);
```

Solved.